# How can i add multiple instances of newsletter subscriptions?

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to display newsletter subscribe in different pages, in different ways. Hence once I have set newsletter : subscribe to home page, it does not apply to other page by default.

How can I can assign it to different pages in different positions?

Answer (score 0):

Each block can be configured in different ways. You can by default give different paths to show or not show your block. Go to /admin/structure/blocks and click on "configure".

If you need more advanced settings, then have a look at the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module. This allows you to define all kind of rules and conditions to show a block. Very powerfull.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am wordering that If I can find some thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872997/how-can-i-create-multiple-different-blocks-in-one-module-in-drupal-6. for drupal 7 It would be helpful for me but i dont get something like this